# FAPI initial checked state for #type => radio

Tags: forms

[Drupal FAPI reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) doesn't have a working example for #type=>radio.  How can I indicate that I want the element to be rendered in a checked state?

```
$form['my_radio_button'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radio',
  '#default_value' => TRUE,
  '#title' => t('Checked by default.'),
);
```

I've tried #default_value TRUE, 1, and different combinations of #value, but nothing seems to work.  Thanks!

Comment: I think that's in there so you can format the actual radio button that's presented within a set of radio buttons.  A singular one wouldn't make much logical sense; what I think you are after is a checkbox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be totally remembering this wrong,  but I'm pretty sure you want to add "checked" as an attribute.

## attributes => array("checked")

Comment: Add the 'checked' attribute (with a value) worked for me, thanks!